# Matrix Addition/Subtraction Properties

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me how the following properties are derived for square matrices of the same size. I know that it is possible to prove/disprove the following properties by showing that they hold for the arbitrary elements of A and B, but is there a quicker way to determine whether these are true or false?

1. $(A−B)^2 =A^2 −2AB+B^2$
2. $(AB)^2 = A^2B^2$
3. $(A+B)^2 =A^2 +2AB+B^2$
4. $(A+B)^2 =A^2 +AB+BA+B^2$
5. $A^2B^2 =A(AB)B$
6. $(A+B)^3 =A^3 +3A^2B+3AB^2 +B^3 $
7. $ (A+B)(A−B)=A^2 −B^2$

Comment: In general, matrix multiplication does not commute so you can start with any result that looks like it is based on commutivity and produce counter examples.

Comment: @John Douma, thanks for the hint. Some may not be so easy to distinguish however. For example, 3 is false, and 4 is true, but 3 is true when AB = BA. Are there any strategies that could be used to eliminate other possibilities?

Comment: You let $A$ and $B$ be general matrices. If you can derive the formula using only properties of matrices then the formula is true. If some special property is required, like $A=B$, then use concrete matrices that  don't have that property to construct a counter-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

1. In general, $AB\ne BA$ (in other words, not commutative), applicable for all but 5
2. Matrix multiplication is distributive, applicable for all but 5
3. Matrix multiplication is associative, you can use it for 5.